# Exception Catching Hierarchy Process

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am implementing exception handling in java with multiple exceptions.

Look at the following scenario:
Function f1 throws Exceptions e1, e2, e3 and e4
and Function f2 catches these.

Now I want to catch e1,e2 explicitly by catch(Exception e1 and e2) and the other exceptions should be caught all in the same block by catch(Exception e)
So e1 and e2 are a special case, and others are all general exceptions.

So will the following work?

```
try{
       //some work`
} catch(ExceptionType1 e1) {
      //do some special logging
} catch (ExceptionType2 e2) {
      //do some special logging
} catch(Exception e) {
     //do general logging for other exceptions
}
```

My question is whether ExceptionType1(e1) will also be caught by Exception e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spec [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.1):

> If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, then there is a choice:
>
> - If the run-time type of V is assignment compatible with (§5.2) a catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement, then the **first** (leftmost) such catch clause is selected. The value V is assigned to the parameter of the selected catch clause, and the Block of that catch clause is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If that block completes normally, then the try statement completes normally.
>   - If that block completes abruptly for any reason, then the try statement completes abruptly for the same reason.

Therefore, at most one catch block will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

For that to work you need to have catch blocks with different Exceptions 
like NullPointerException NumberFormatException and the general exception will be caught by catch block with Exception parameter since Exception is the super class of all Exceptions

```
try{
   //some work`
} catch(NullPointerException e1) {
  //do some special logging
} catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
  //do some special logging
} catch(Exception e) {
 //do general logging for other exceptions
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant the same thing, I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code will catch all Exceptions in `catch(Exception e1){...}`

The other `catch`-blocks are unused. If you want to handle different `Exception`-types on different way you have to give the `catch(...)` other `Exception`-types.

Like

```
try{
}catch(IOException e1){
  // Do sth
}
catch(NullPointerException e2){
  // Do sth else
}
// and so on...
```

Comment: @SambhavSharma your Exception handling will exit after the first caught Exception. So if it fits in ExceptionType1 it will exit after the corresponding catch-block.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple catch blocks with the same class i.e. `Exception`

If you have multiple `Exceptions` you need to create a separate class for each one and make your catch block for a specific class

Just be aware the order of your catch block must go from the more specific to the more generic class

e.g.

```
try {

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());       
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Throwable e) {
  System.err.println("Caught Throwable: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

So in the above code if the exception is of `FileNotFoundException` only the first `catch` will be executed. Otherwise the `catch` block with `Exception` is going to be executed for any instance of `Exception` class that was not caught in the previous `catch` blocks

At the end `Throwable` will catch anything that does not inherent from `Exception` such as `Error`

Comment: Sorry I meant the same, I have edited the question now, also I think I got the answer.